# How to add a commit done on a restored branch to an old PR?

Tags: github, pull-request

In the PR , after I merged a branch and deleted it, I restored the branch again on the PR.
Locally, then I made changes to the branch and pushed it to the remote branch. The commit is available on the remote branch but it does not come up in the existing merged PR.
After I compare and Pull Request, it is creating a new PR.

Is it possible to add the commit to the old PR itself?

Comment: Think about what that would _mean_. You'd have to rewrite the merge commit (or multiple commits, if you rebased rather than merging or squashing), which would mean rewriting every commit that depended on it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't re-open the pull request if it was merged.